# How to find the dimension of a Quotient Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $c_0 = \{(x_n) : x_n \in\mathbb R ,\ x_n \to 0 \}$ and $M=\{(x_n)\in c_0:x_1 + x_2 + \cdots +x_{10} =0\}$. I need to find the dimension of  quotient  space
>   $c_{0}/M$.

Now I know that $c_{0}/M=\{M + (x_n ): (x_n)\in c_{0}\}$. But after that I am stuck.

I don't understand how should I use the property of Vector space $M$ to get the dimension

Can anyone please help me here ?

Thank you

Comment: It has been a while, but from what I just read, two sequences are in the same equivalence class if their difference is in $M$, which means that the first ten terms of their difference sum to zero. Seems like that would mean that the dimension is ten minus one, if I’m understanding quotient spaces.

Comment: Hint. Define a map $f:c_0\to\mathbb R$ by $f((x_n))=x_1+\cdots +x_{10}$.

Comment: @user26857: I'm sorry I don't quite understand your hint,Could you please elaborate

Comment: What's the kernel of that map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimension is $1$: note that any $(x_n) \in c_0$ can be moved into $M$ by only changing $x_{10}$.

This observation can be translated so that the sequences ($x_i=0$ for $i\ne 10$) form a full representative set for the cosets.

Comment: I have one doubt , You said Any $x_n \in c_0$ can be  moved to M by changing $x_{10}$. I cannot understand this part,For eg: if $x_n \in c_0$ then $x_n $ can be written as $x_n = x_1, x_2,x_3,x_4 \ldots x_9 ,-x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4-x_5-x_6-x_7-x_8-x_9$ do you mean this ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, change only one coordinate (the tenth), the rest of the sequence stays fixed.